# Concatenate and build URL

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, mustache

I am trying to get the user to a certain URL when he clicks on a table element. Using Mustache templates, I have the following:

```
{{#each data.Items}}            
<tr>                                        
<td data-url="/Test/Email/Edit/" + {{this.Id}}>
<span class="link">{{this.Name}}</span>
</td>
</tr>
```

data-url always returns "/Test/Email/Edit/" and ignores the Id part in the end. 
How do I make the data-url concatenate the Id part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td data-url="/Test/Email/Edit/{{this.Id}}">
```

Comment: I tried that but I was missing one of the curly braces. Thank you  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
{{#data.Items}}
  <tr>                                        
    <td data-url="/Test/Email/Edit/{{Id}}">
      <span class="link">{{Name}}</span>
    </td>
  </tr> 
{{/data.Items}}
```